# Admin ManyToManyWoes and ContentTypes problems

Tags: django-admin

I am trying to create network graph-like models, where I have Person, Organisation, Funder, Research Project etc... And I have connecting models of Relationships and Relation.

I'm fine with the notion of making my own interface to work with these objects, and ensuring objects are saved before they are added to relations, but for the life of me I can't get the Admin interface to work.

What happens is the Relation inlines just show up as blank OR I get the error the object doesn't exist after I have added them to form, when I save it all blows up.

I have created a full example and populated a few People, Organisations, etc in a SQLite db so that you can see it action... I've been struggling with this for years and despite poring over the docs for days and days, I can never quite get it to work. I'm hoping I have just got one concept wrong but as I said, this is driving me nuts, and what I generally do is, give up and make a model that is less "pure".

https://github.com/everythingability/manytomanywoes

*p.s As an aside, it would be nice to have working examples to look at for some features with Django, wouldn't it?*